# SQL Server - Database import from CSV/XLS

Tags: sql-server, database

Have a basic question regarding how to solve this import problem.

Have a CSV with ca. 40 fields, that need to be inserted across ca. 5 tables.

Let say tables are like this

```
tpeople

Column Name | Datatype
GUID        | uniqueidentifier
Fname       | varchar
Lname       | varchar
UserEnteredGUID | uniqueidentifier


tcompany

Column Name | Datatype
GUID        | uniqueidentifier
CompanyTypeGUID | uniqueidentifier
PrintName       | varchar
Website | varchar

tcompanyLocation

Column Name | Datatype
GUID        | uniqueidentifier
CompanyGUID | uniqueidentifier
City        | varchar
```

As we can see database is normalized and we can see different GUIDs.

My question is, when I will write for example a Python script to enter data, how should I handle the GUIDs?

For example I want to add:

```
Fname: John
Lname: Smith
Company: IBM
Location: New York
Website: www.ibm.com
UserEntered: Admin
```

How do I make sure all relations/GUID are correct?

I would try:

```
insert into tpeople(GUID,Fname,Lname,UserEnteredGUID) values("","John","Smith",???)
```

**Question**

How to get UserEnteredGUID? Do I have to make a select on GUID from UserEntered table where user equals "Admin"?

Or here:

```
insert into tcompany(GUID,CompanyTypeGUID,PrintName,Website) values("",??,"IBM","www.ibm.com")
```

Here the same? How should I handle CompanyTypeGUID? It would also mean that I have to populate CompanyType table BEFORE I add anything to tcompany table?

This does not look right to me, kind of thinking from back to forward, thinking how each table is connected to the other one .... there has to be a way to insert records to normalized database where this GUID, Foreign Keys stuff has to be somehow automated.

I hope somebody got my problem and can guide me towards solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You may start by getting new GUID by calling the built-in function NEWID() to get unique identifier value then insert it in your different tables according to the table relations.

Comment: but do you have create tables from scratch or you have got already them?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Tables are ready... I am just overwhelmed by the relations between them ... SOOOO MANY GUIDS ... one insert and I have to think about 4-8 tables to update before or during the update. Is there solution to see what needs to be updated or some cleaner/smarter way of doing this?

Comment: Gosh I sure hope all those GUIDS are not also your clustered indexes. If at all possible it would be MUCH better if you could use real names for these instead of GUID. One of my biggest pet peeves is columns changing names across tables. It is never a GUID it is always a CompanyTypeGUID.